# Query with join doesn't select related object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to join the table STUDENT to STUDY_PROGRAM. STUDENT to STUDY_PROGRAM is a one to many relationship. The query on a simple natural join didn't give the expected result.  Debugging shows that the query result didn't have 'program' columns.

```
(Pdb) print mystudents[0].program
*** AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'program'
```

```
def students():
    mystudentinfo = mydb.session.query(Student).join(StudyProgram)
    return render_template('administration/students.html', studentinfo = mystudentinfo)

class Student(mydb.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'STUDENT'
    study_no = mydb.Column(mydb.String(20), primary_key = True)
    std_first_name = mydb.Column(mydb.String(64))
    std_last_name = mydb.Column(mydb.String(64))
    std_birthdate = mydb.Column(mydb.Date())
    std_email = mydb.Column(mydb.String(62))
    std_password = mydb.Column(mydb.String())
    study_programs = mydb.relationship('StudyProgram', backref='student')
    project_apps = mydb.relationship('ProjectApp', backref='student')

class StudyProgram(mydb.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'STUDY_PROGRAM'
    study_no = mydb.Column(mydb.String(20), mydb.ForeignKey('STUDENT.study_no'), primary_key = True)
    program = mydb.Column(mydb.String(100), primary_key = True)
    degree_type = mydb.Column(mydb.String(8), primary_key = True)
    reg_date = mydb.Column(mydb.Date())
    status = mydb.Column(mydb.String(20))
    earned_ECTs = mydb.Column(mydb.Numeric(4, 1))
    reg_ECTs = mydb.Column(mydb.Numeric(3, 1))
    tot_ECTs = mydb.Column(mydb.Numeric(4, 1))
    graduation_date = mydb.Column(mydb.Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

The query didn't select any of `Program` because SQLAlchemy treats joins separately from selects.

The [loading strategy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/loading_relationships.html) for the relationship can be changed using the [`options()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.options) call on the query.  Since you are not doing any filtering on `StudyProgram`, you can omit the `join` and set the [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) option instead.

```
students = db.session.query(Student).options(db.joinedload('study_programs'))
```

Now the `study_programs` relationship will be loaded during the main query, rather than as a separate query.  If you do need to join for filtering, you can use the [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) option instead.

To access the programs for each student, use the relationship.  For example:

```
for s in students:
    print(s.first_name)

    for p in s.study_programs:
        print(p.program)

    print()
```

If you used `joinedload` this will not issue any queries except the first one to get the students.  If you did not, the default behavior of a relationship is to issue a `SELECT` when it is accessed, so you will incur one query per student.

---

The reason for your specific error is that you named the relationship attribute `study_programs`, not `program`.